# Making Unique Playername for my multiplayer game using unet Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

im having difficulties in creating unique player name system for my multiplayer game. i've tried using [Command] to get playername variable[SyncVar] and send data to server then send data from server to client using [ClientRpc] but i've got no luck. hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get uniqueId from NetID.

```
NetworkInstanceId gamePlayeruniqueNetID = gamePlayer.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().netId;
```